# Pickle append mode is not adding anything in the end (python)

Tags: python, batch-file, append, pickle

I have already created a .dat file containing 4 columns with column heading as:
Name    Class/Sec    Boards%      Remarks
I need to make a program which inputs from the teacher about the students and then append it to the batch file but its not working

```
# program to show various
# operations that can be 
# applied to binary files

import pickle

# creating a student portfolio

# reading the student portfolio file
def r_portfolio():

    with open('testing.dat', 'rb') as f:
        data = pickle.load(f)
        print(data)


# writing in the student portfolio
def w_portfolio():
    
    # taking inputs
    name = input('Enter the name of the student: ')
    c_sec = input("Enter the class and sec: ")
    per = input("Enter boards%(10th): ")
    remarks = input("Enter remarks: ")

    entry = name + "\t\t" + c_sec + "\t\t" + per + "\t\t" + remarks

    # dumping the info into the file
    with open('testing.dat', 'ab') as f:
        pickle.dump(entry, f)

    # previewing the change
    preview = input("Do you want to preview the portfolio(y/n): ")
    if preview.lower() == 'y':
        r_portfolio()

w_portfolio()
```

[image]

Comment: If multiple objects are pickled in this way, only the first is loaded. Repeat the load until end of file is reached.